# recursively parse json in javascript to retrieve certain keys' values

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary, recursion

I am new to javascript and every time i try learning it, I just end up in an immense amount of frustration and disgust ! No offense, but this is my opinion or perhaps I am too stupid to not understand how it works at all.

I have a simple requirement. I have a pretty deeply nested dictionary (which is what it is called in many backend languages) at hand. To be more specific it is the raw text of a postman collection. The collection itself could have multiple nested directories.

Now all I want to do is to be able to parse this dictionary and do something with it recursively.

For example, if I had to do the same in python I would do it as simply as :

```
 def createRequests(self, dic):
        total_reqs = 0
        headers = {}
        print type(dic)
        keys = dic.keys()
        if 'item' in keys:
            print "Folder Found. Checking for Indivisual request inside current folder . .  \n"

            self.item_list = dic.get('item')

            for each_item in self.item_list:    
                self.folder.append(self.createRequests(each_item))


        else:
            print "Found Indivisual request. Appending. . .  \n"
            temp_list = []
            temp_list.append(dic)
            self.requestList.append(temp_list)
            return self.requestList
```

where `dic` would be my dictionary that I want to parse. 
Is there any simple and straight forward way to do the same in Javascript?

Let's just say all I want to do is that if I have a text file that has properly formed json data in it and whose contents have been read into `dataReadFromFile` and then it has been converted into a JSON as :

`var obj = JSON.parse(dataReadFromFile);`

is there any simple and easy way to convert this JSON to dictionary or the `dataReadFromFile` directly into a dictionary such that I can say something like dictioanry.keys() if I wanted a list of the keys in it.

Note that the content of the file is not fixed. It may have multiple levels of nesting, which may not be known beforehand.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `JSON.parse()` *does* convert this JSON to the JS equivalent of a dictionary, and you can do `Object.keys(obj)` to get the keys.

Comment: An example of your input?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you. That is exactly what I wanted. But why does it have to be so cryptic ? Why couldn't I simply say `obj.keys()` instead of `Object.keys(obj)` which just does not look straight !

Comment: Because that's how the method works .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @qre0ct what if your object had a key call keys? How would the parse know you wanted to reference the property or the method? Seems like being separate is better.

Comment: @epascarello that comes down to philosophy I suppose. Couldn't I always say for the case you mentioned, it should have been like `obj.keys()` to get all the keys, where the name of each key is nothing but a string alone, and hence could be anything including the string `keys` ? 
And then if I at all had to refer to the value of the key `keys` I could simply say `obj.get('keys')` !
However, I do agree with @charlietfl point. That's how it is and I definitely need to appreciate rather than condemn the difference between 2 very different languages as python and JS & of course learn the latter.

Comment: @qre0ct And Object.keys() is rather new in the specifictation. The reason why you can do it with Map is it was built with getters and setters and you can not directly access the content, you do not have that option with an object. If you want a map, than send it back as a array of arrays and do `new Map([["foo", "bar"],["hello", "world"]])`